# Android EditText with Swype Keyboard typing issues

Tags: android, android-edittext, swipe

I have a user that is having problems when she attemps to type in my app.  The device she is using is the Motorola Electrify running Gingerbread and she is using the Swype Keyboard on her phone.  When she attemps to add text to an existing item it just overtypes unless she uses the Swyping gestures to build the words.

Just to be clear I dont have any listeners coded that are cauing this.  I have tested with the other stock keyboard on her phone (Multi Touch) and everything seems to work fine.

An example of what we are seeing: Press A the A appears on the screen then you press n it replaces the A.

Here is the layout for the edit text:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editor_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.72"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
    android:singleLine="false" >
</EditText>
```

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out @DKerkman? I've tried all the flags and I can't disable the Swype suggestion popup :(.

Answer (score -1):

So I was the lead Android developer for Swype until May of this year.  So I'll do my old friends a solid and give some free tech support.  What version of Swype is she using?  And is she doing anything funny with inserting her own text into the edit text or losing focus from the edit box?  If she turns off predictive text does it still happen?

The problem she mentions sounds like a problem I saw with some custom implementations of EditText where they did not properly implement getExtractedText and our predictive text solution expected to be able to retrieve the previously typed text from the editor (to work around a variety of bugs in yet other apps).  But if you're using a stock EditText that shouldn't be the case.  Let me know the answers to the above and I'll see what I can drag out of year old memories.

Comment: I will check what version of Swype she is using and get back to you.  When I was watching her she was not doing anything funny other than single pressing the keys like you would with a normal keyboard :) I suggested turning Swype off if thats how she was going to type but she said sometimes she likes to use it.  I will also test with perdictive text off and let you know.  I am using the standard EditText also.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: She is using Swype version 3.20.86.28200.  I noticed that if I turn off Word suggestion in the sype settings this issues does not happen.  

Here is a youtube video of the issue:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUqhkGdyKhI&feature=youtube_gdata_player

Comment: Ok, so it is the bug I'm thinking of, but you shouldn't see that happening in a normal EditText (unless they shipped a broken version, but then you'd see if globally).  The one thing that does look unusual to me in the xml is the textAutoCorrect part of the input type-  usually that's assumed.  Try removing it and see if it changes things, it may be putting android in some odd mode where it tries to do autocorrent and not the keyboard.

Comment: I will try to remove the textAutoCorrect and send them an updated to see if that fixes the issue.  Just to see if this sparks any other ideas I have 2 users that have the exact same phone (and same version of swype) only one of them is seeing this issue and I had them test with the same account to verify it was not a data issue.

Comment: Just as a follow up I tried removing the textAutoCorrect from the InputType and that didn't fix the issue.  Did you have any other ideas?

Comment: Where is the 'solid' you promised @GabeSechan? I also have this issue. I can't disable the suggestions a swype keyboard.

Comment: He wasn't trying to disable Swype suggestions.  The only way to do that (at least on versions this old, unsure on the newest versions) is to specify a field input type that would make Swype turn it off.  Using textNoSuggestions might work.  So might visiblePassword.  Beyond that I can't help, I don't have code access anymore.